# Probability of getting a satisfactory grade on a test.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two students are solving a test of $4$ problems. The first student solves each problem independently with probability $\frac13$; the second student solves each problem independently with probability  $\frac23$. To get a satisfactory grade for the test, a student needs to solve at least $2$ problems.

At first, each student has enough time to try to solve each problem on his own. That is, some time after the start of the test, each student knows which problems he solved (we consider that if a student thinks that he solved the problem, then it really is so) and which he didn't (in this case, he will leave the solution blank).

Then, the first student starts cheating. For each problem he didn't solve, he will copy the second student's solution if it is not left blank. If he is caught cheating, he will automatically get an unsatisfactory grade (even if he had already solved at least $2$ problems by himself).

Assume that, for each problem he wants to copy, the teacher has a $\frac12$ chance of catching him cheat.

**Problems**

1. Find the probability that the first student gets a satisfactory grade.
2. If the first student got a satisfactory grade, what is probability that cheating helped him (that is, had he not cheated, he would have solved less than $2$ problems).

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also for clarity:  "towards the end of the test" isn't very precise.  Do you mean the last question?  The last two questions?  Something else?  Do the students somehow know if they have answered correctly or not?  Also, the proctor's timing doesn't make sense. If they check once a minute (on a schedule, let's guess) and it takes a full minute to cheat, then the proctor will catch the cheater with probability $1$.

Comment: I apologize for inaccurate statement. I've edited it for clarity. Well, I can't come up with a good solution.  The only thing that comes to mind is to consider all cases: there are 2^8 cases - which problems first student solved by himself and which second did. So we can find probability of each case and then because we know how many problems first student wants to copy we can find probability of he will be noticed by teacher. But there are too many options to sort through them manually. There must be a solution that requires considering smaller number of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually only $5$ cases to consider. Let $S$ be the event that the first student gets a satisfactory grade, and $A$ be the number of problems he solved by himself originally.

For (1), find $P(S|A=i)$ and $P(A=i)$ for each $i=0,\dots, 4$ to get $P(S)$.

For (2), you want $P(A<2|S)$. By Bayes rule, this is $P(S|A<2)P(A<2)/P(S)$, which you can get from your computations in (1).

Can you complete this by yourself now?

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution using conditional probability. Thanks!